# List comprehension output is None

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I'm new to python and I wanted to try to use list comprehension but outcome I get is None.

```
print
wordlist = ['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit']
letterlist = []
letterlist = [letterlist.append(letter) for word in wordlist for letter in word if letter not in letterlist]
print letterlist

# output i get: [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
# expected output: ['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'b', 'i']
```

Why is that? It seems that it works somehow because I get expected number of outcomes (9) but all of them are None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list.append(element)` doesn’t return anything – it appends an element to the list in-place.

Your code could be rewritten as:

```
wordlist = ['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit']
letterlist = [letter for word in wordlist for letter in word]
letterlist = list(set(letterlist))
print letterlist
```

… if you really want to use a list comprehension, or:

```
wordlist = ['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit']
letterset = set()
for word in wordlist:
    letterset.update(word)
print letterset
```

… which is arguably clearer. Both of these assume order doesn’t matter. If it does, you could use OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
letterlist = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys("".join(wordlist)).keys())
print letterlist
```

Comment: it works great thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

`list.append` returns `None`. You need to adjust the expression in the list comprehension to return letters.

```
wordlist = ['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit']
letterset = set()
letterlist = [(letterset.add(letter), letter)[1]
              for word in wordlist
              for letter in word
              if letter not in letterset]
print letterlist
```

Comment: Cute, but I _hatess_ list comps with side effects. Still, I guess it's better than filling a list comp with a bunch of `None`s...

Answer (score 0):

If order doesn't matter, do this:

```
 resultlist = list({i for word in wordlist for i in word})
```